# How to set card ownership in Trello?

Tags: trello

My team uses Trello for tracking software development tasks.

Our workflow is described here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/22013/14928

Most of the time we have several members assigned to a card. 
We do it to keep these people informed.

What we need and don't have in Trello is card ownership. So this will help to filter all cards are waiting for you.

Could you recommend any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is different notions of 'Subscribed' to a card and 'Assigned' to a card. I can't think of a good workaround for you right now (short of just noting the card owner in the description field), but we are looking at the idea of board or card subscriptions, and an individual 'card owner' might make a good plugin.